# What`s the template engine using in the Lets-Chat?

Tags: letschat

I want to build a chat project base on lets-chat project https://github.com/sdelements/lets-chat. However I can't find out what`s the template engine it uses.

Answer (score 0):

I found that. It`s nunjucks.  http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/  and we can find all Express compliant Template Engine [Here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/wiki#template-engines)